# iMac 27" shutting down during Windows 7 install

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I've got a problem with my Mid-2010 iMac 27" where when trying to Bootcamp Windows 7 x64 (Ultimate edition) it simply wont get past the expanding files stage.

Despite numerous attempts to use USB and the retail DVD, it will take about a second to copy the files and then will start to expand files.

After a few minutes of hearing the DVD drive spinning, it shuts down.

Has anyone ever encountered this?

I'm currently downloading the latest ISO from MSDN to try however I'm not holding my breath lol.

Look forward to hearing from you all :)

Thanks

Gavin

**Specs**

```
iMac 27 Mid-2010
Processor: 2.93ghz Intel Core i7
Memory: 16gb 1333 MHz DDR3
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 5750 1024mb
Software: OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
```

**Partitions**

```
Filesystem    512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   292863368 173193648 119157720    60% 21713204 14894715   59%   /
devfs                369       369         0   100%      642        0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk0s4   195642688      4608 195638080     1%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/BOOTCAMP
map -hosts             0         0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home          0         0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /home
```

Comment: Please, has anyone got any idea's?

Comment: Gavin, when you say it has shut down, boot up into Mac again. Go to `Boot Camp Assistant` and tell me the options it has listed. If it has partially installed, it should say `Remove Windows 7 Installation` for example.

Comment: Hi @sameetandpotatoes, when it turns off and I turn it back on again, 95% of the time it will stay at a grey screen with the DVD drive spinning and then turn off again. When I finally get to the boot options screen, I load up OSX and it gives me the option to remove the partition. Not sure what could be causing it :(

Comment: Can you edit your answer and include your specs, such as RAM and version of OS X? Also, include more details such as your partition (how much space you have allocated). This may be occurring due to a drive or partition error, so in `Disk Utility` in OS X, hit `Verify Disk` and `Repair Disk` for both partitions and try again.

Comment: Also, I was reading on [forums](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/running-windows-anything-else-your-mac/197287-cant-install-windows-7-ultimate-imac-late-2009-a.html) that sometimes the drivers that they install in Bootcamp Assistant are necessary for the installation to complete. Therefore, stay away from the retail DVD and instead have a USB flash drive (maybe use 2.0 instead of 3.0 if applicable; also should be 8 GB at least) that has the ISO and the drivers on it.

Comment: Hi @sameetandpotatoes, as requested, I have updated the question with spec's and HDD partitions. I have tried both Bootcamp with the DVD and with a USB pen drive created using the Windows 7 USB Drive creator. Verified both the Mac and Bootcamp partitions. Wasn't offered a repair on the Mac however was on the Bootcamp so took it. Will try again :)

Comment: When you try it again, make sure you remove the existing Windows 7 installation that you said it had. Also, this is kind of a redundant thing to say but make sure you are giving Windows 7 enough space (50 GB mininum).

Comment: When in OS X, do you have any available Software Updates?  Do you have any EFI or SMC updates available?

Comment: Hi @da4 - No updates available, all completely up to date. Another attempt I'm going to try now is to install using a UEFI USB Drive, as my Samsung laptop worked nicely with that. sameetandpotatoes - Will do, I've been creating a 100gb partition each time.

Comment: UEFI USB Drive failed, when attempting to boot from it, it freezes. With my Samsung Laptop, it has a Secure Boot functionality, which makes it difficult to install another OS. Out of interest, does the Intel Mac's (specifically, mine) have something like this?

Comment: "...These systems used EFI instead of Open Firmware, which had been used on its previous PowerPC-based systems.[32] On 5 April 2006, Apple first released Boot Camp, which produces a Windows drivers disk and a non-destructive partitioning tool to allow the installation of Windows XP or Vista without requiring a reinstallation of Mac OS X. A firmware update was also released that added BIOS compatibility to its EFI implementation. Subsequent Macintosh models shipped with the newer firmware.[33]" [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes - thanks, I'm aware it as the UEFI/EFI boot functionality, however on my Samsung laptop, it has something called Secure Boot which prevented me from installing anything over the pre-configured OS without modifying the BIOS first. I was hoping to find out whether the MAC had such a setting that could also be disabled to resolve this?

Comment: Gavin, sorry for not responding. As cmurf pointed out, this obviously is not normal. Do you have AppleCare on it? You may have to take it to the Genius Bar and receive an answer there. Doesn't sound like a software problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

Get Temperature Monitor to see if it's heat related...

http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/12381/temperature-monitor

iStat Menus...

http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/

And/or iStat Pro...

http://www.islayer.com/apps/istatpro/

Open Console in Utilities & see if there are any clues in the system log for Date & Time of the last shutdown/crash & the next start up.

Comment: Hi @KingKongFrog - Would this not show an issue whilst using the Mac normally? Nothing in the logs that I can see of, however I'll try again and see if I can pin point it down.

Answer (score 0):

The iMac powers off abruptly, during Windows installation at the 'Expanding files" stage? Have you applied the most recent firmware update for this iMac model, it sorta sounds like it's overheating, or has bad memory. An abrupt shutdown in the middle of installing the system isn't correct behavior.

Comment: He has 10.8.4...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. While this post does add potentially useful information to the discussion, it is less of an answer and more of a request for additional information that would be better posted as a comment to the original question.

Comment: Hi @cmurf, yes the machine literally just switches off. You can hear the DVD drive spinning and as the screen goes blank (at 0% on "Expanding files"), the drive stops spinning also.